# Convert string from Latin-1 to UTF-8 and back to Latin-1

Tags: python

A system (not under my control) sends a `latin-1` encoded string (such as Öland) which I can convert to `utf-8` but not back to `latin-1`.

Consider this code:

```
text = '\xc3\x96land' # This is what the external system sends
iso = text.encode(encoding='latin-1') # this is my best guess
print(iso.decode('utf-8'))
print(u"Öland".encode(encoding='latin-1'))
```

This is the output:

```
Öland
b'\xd6land'
```

Now, how to I mimic the system?
Obviously `'\xc3\x96land'` is not `'\xd6land'`

Comment: Are you sure the input is Latin-1? "Ö" should not need two bytes to encode. In fact 0xD6 looks right: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1

Comment: To be honest no. Latin-1 is just my best guess.

Comment: Maybe your input is UTF-8 already? `Ö c3 96 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS`

Comment: @Thilo Latin letters do need 2 byte encoding ^^ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout

Comment: @discipline: Not in Latin-1, they don't. In UTF-8, yeah, Ö is 0xC396.

Comment: You're using Python 3; `text` is in Unicode already; then you encode it into latin 1, getting `Ã\x96land` in latin 1; which you decode as UTF-8, which is `Öland` now as Unicode text... `'\xc3\x96land'` in an Unicode string doesn't make sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

if your external system sends it to you then you should first decode it rather than encoding it since it is sent as encoded.

you don't have to encode the encoded!!

`hey=u"Öland".encode('latin-1')
print hey`

gives output like this `?land`

`print hey.decode('latin-1')`
gives output like this `Öland`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the external system send the data in utf-8 already.
Converting the string forth and back works like this now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

text = '\xc3\x96land'
encoded = text.encode(encoding='raw_unicode_escape')
print(encoded)
utf8 = encoded.decode('utf-8')
print(utf8)

mimic = utf8.encode('utf-8', 'unicode_escape')
print(mimic)
```

And the output

```
b'\xc3\x96land'
Öland
b'\xc3\x96land'
```

Thank you for your support!